# Workflow: Clean Line Art

Tags: eevee-render-engine, workflow, freestyle

I know there on some talented Blender user on here, and I have been looking for methods with Blender Eevee to make clean line art like the work of [@beesandbombs on Twitter](https://twitter.com/beesandbombs/status/1487468975453884418):
[image]

Unfortunately, I have been stumped with the line rendering part of this:
[image]

I have been using freestyle in Eevee, and I can't seem to make the lines look, well, good. They look very pixelated and inconsistent.

Here's a close up of the reference and mine:

[image]

Here's [my .blend so far](https://pasteall.org/blend/5177e9a181e14c039b4b4947b7d54b99) (really doubt this would help anyone that can offer advice). I would appreciate any guidance on workflow for this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few aspects of your .blend which might defeat he clean render of Freestyle strokes.

- The **Geometry** of your object. Maybe you created the top face by extruding edges, not faces? The inside is packed with internal faces. They all have to go, really, there's a danger of depth-errors. Just leave the outside skin.
- The **Material** of your object. No need for *Principled BSDF* here.. you don't want to simulate the response of the surface to light at all. Just use an *Emission*, which, in EEVEE, is flat color.
- The **Render** settings. Viewport 'Sampling' was set to 16, but Render was set to 1. With only 1 sample per pixel, there's no anti-aliasing. 16 seems to be enough.
- Freestyle's **Line Set** settings. You were relying on the 'Visible' setting alone to determine which edges are stroked. I'm surprised that works at all. Maybe it's the internal faces. :). Instead, in this case, it would seem to be best to explicitly tell Freestyle which edges to render, by marking them as Freestyle Edges. Then  in the View Layers tab, Freestyle > Line Set panel, set Freestyle to pick up only those edges:

[image]

After that, the render's looking OK:

[image]

You can find a revised version of your file [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/1b80e861445c49c4aa091a6085dd7055)

All credit to [@beesandbombs](https://twitter.com/beesandbombs/status/1487468975453884418) for a lovely idea.. I couldn't resist implementing it in Geometry Nodes:

[image]

[image]